# R iterative assign using different data frames

Tags: r, loops, iteration, assign

I made a user defined function...

From a vector x, y, f(x,y) returns list of (x,y,z)...

Now I want to do iterations of

```
data1 <- f(x,y)
data2 <- f(data1$x, data1$y)
data3 <- f(data2$x, data2$y)
data4 <- f(data3$x, data3$y)
```

and so on...

Is there a way to make a loop for this?

I tried to use paste function

```
data1 <- f(x,y)
for (i = 2:10) {
    assign(paste("data",i,sep=""), f(paste("data",i-1,"$x",sep=""), paste("data",i-1,"$y",sep=""))
}
```

but it gets error since input becomes "data1$x" which is string not numeric.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! My advice would be to make a list of your datasets, then you will have no problem with your loop and you will have all the data-sets ready in one data structure for future use.

Comment: On a more general note, a solution to your problem could be to use "parse"... but you should not do that, see `fortunes::fortune(106)`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. With help of Christoffer, I succeed to make your idea work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vincent just replied you can make a list, and a list of lists etc. This will make it easier to produce what you want.

I made an example for you:

```
x <- 1:10; y <- 11:20
f <- function(x, y) {return(list(x = x+1, y = y+1))}

data <- c()
data[[1]] <- f(x, y)
for(i in 2:10){
  data[[i]] <- f(data[[i-1]]$x, data[[i-1]]$y)
}
```

You can then get x from time i with `data[[i]]$x`.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm still confusing with data[[i]] and data[i] but it worked perfectly!!

Comment: It's kind of like data[i] shows you the elements in the list, while data[[i]] extracts them. 
I'm sure you can find it more elegantly written somewhere else..